# Default language with one "values" folder

Tags: android

I just wrote an android application and I'm about to publish it. But I have a problem, the APK is uploaded ok, but when writing the information of the application in Google Play, detects "Spanish" as the default language.

In the code, I only have a unique folder named values. Shouldn't it detect default language as english? Or where is this default language configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have accidently checked Spanish when you were creating the listing. You can click on "Add translations", pick English, then switch it to the default language. Afterwards you should see a "Manage translations" option where you can remove Spanish from your languages. [image]